# How to run expressJS CLI from local installation

Tags: node.js, express, command-line-interface

I've a question regarding ExpressJS local installation (I'm aware of the global usage but it's not the case for me right now).

I've a the following project:

```
/my-project
    |- package.json (express included)
    |- node_modules (express installed)
    |- app.js
```

now I can use expressJS within the app.js module but, how can I use it's CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still install the global version too. They will be installed in different locations.

Or you can invoke the local one in your directory -

```
./node_modules/express/bin/express
```

Edit: 
The above is not the case with latest versions. It is true in the one i have installed (3.4.8).

Seems in the latest version (4.0.0) they have separated the app generator from express core.

If you want to install the generator locally too, do

`npm install express-generator`

And then

`./node_modules/express-generator/bin/express`

Comment: the thing is I've no 'bin' directory inside

Comment: I have version 3.4.8 installed and it has the bin directory. You can install it using `npm install express@3.4.8`.

Or i think you can also try `node node_modules/express/index.js`

Comment: by the way - do You know maybe is this some kind of the version issue? did some of express versions did not have embedded CLI ?

Comment: Seems they have separated the app generator from express core. if you want to install that locally too, do `npm install express-generator@3`. And then `./node_modules/express-generator/bin/express`

Comment: try the `./node_modules/express/.bin/express` path